# How to add text to end of line when pattern is matched?

Tags: shell, sed, line-editor

inputs:

```
line1 with the PATTERN that contains ( ) 
line2 with the PATTERN that contains ( ) 
lineN with the PATTERN that contains ( )
```

outputs:

```
line1 with the PATTERN that contains ( ) ;
line2 with the PATTERN that contains ( ) ;
...
lineN with the PATTERN that contains ( ) ;
```

I tried this:

```
find . -name "test.txt" -print | xargs sed -i "/PATTERN/ s/$)/); /g"
```

but it didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

The `$` matches the end of the line, so your pattern should be `)$` instead of `$)` like in your example.

Also, you don't need `xargs` here, it's safer to use the `-exec` flag of `fine`:

```
find . -name test.txt -exec sed -i '/PATTERN/ s/)$/); /' '{}' +
```

If your version of find doesn't work with `+` at the end, then use `\;` instead (thank you [@glenn-jackman](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/4667/glenn-jackman)):

```
find . -name test.txt -exec sed -i '/PATTERN/ s/)$/); /' '{}' \;
```

Finally, there's no need for the `g` flag in a `s/something$//` idiom, as there is only one occurrence of `$` per line.

Comment: You'll gain some efficiency with `-exec ... +` instead of `-exec ... \;`, if your find allows it.

Answer (score 2):

```
perl -ipe 's/$/;/ if /PATTERN/'
```

This will add a `;` at the end if the line contains `PATTERN`.

Comment: where is the input file passed here?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `PATTERN` is actually `( )` and that something might go in between the `( )` and that they are not necessarily at the end of the line:

```
sed -i '/(.*)/ s/$/ ;/' test.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
sed --in-place '/PATTERN/s/.*/&;/' /path/to/file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`ex`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ex_(text_editor)) (which is equivalent to `vi -e`/`vim -e`).

One file:

```
ex +"g/local/s/$/;/g" -cwq foo.txt
```

All `test.txt` files recursively:

```
ex +"bufdo g/local/s/$/;/g" -cxa **/test.txt
```

<sup>Note: Make sure that [globbing option](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/globstar-new-bash-globbing-option) (`**`) is enabled by: `shopt -s globstar` if your shell supports it.</sup>

<sup>Note: The `:bufdo` command is not [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ex.html).</sup>

Comment: note bufdo is not POSIX http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ex.html